# How to set the line width of vector graphics in ConTeXt?

Tags: graphics, context, context-mkiv

I have several vector graphics in PDF format that I want to place in my ConTeXt document. I  added them with `\externalfigure[graphic.pdf]`, some scaled to different sizes. All of the lines in these graphics use a single line width.

I want all of these graphics, regardless of their scale, to have a consistent line width. Is there any way to set the line width of the graphics from within the ConTeXt document so that the line width of all of the lines is the same as the line width in the document's table rules?

Comment: This command just includes the `pdf` figure as created and only allows scaling of the figure as a whole.  It does not do anything to the figure's internal structure.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the figure to  MetaPost and set necessary pen size e.g.

```
pickup pencircle scaled 2pt;
```